# Apache complete reset

Tags: apache2, default

I cannot get Apache work again.

I tried `sudo apt-get purge apache2` followed by `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Also `sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apache2`

Nothing!

I'd like to go back to the default configuration.

Please, can you help?

Comment: what error you are getting ?  logs `/var/log/apache2/` ? .  error or log message will be helpful to understand exact problem .

Comment: cat /var/log/apache2/error.log returns:

[Tue Oct 11 22:15:50 2016] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/user/webs/www.domain.it/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

I then realized that I accidentally deleted .htaccess file. If I create a new .htaccess file (an empty one), Apache sends the default index.php file as is, and a download dialog box appears.